# how to get request payload data from jquery ajax one its invoked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am invoking multiple ajax call using `jQuery.ajax()` to a single url with different request payload data in parallel.

i want to get the request payload data for the ajax call which got failed dur any 400 or 500 errors.

I tried using jqXHR object of `function error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` but didn't found any way to get request

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Questions of this nature really help to have a JSFiddle or an example of your code in the question. Also @CodeiSir provided the best link for info.